# Dynamic default time for p:calendar

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

When using primefaces p:calendar with time it defaults to 00:00. I need dynamic behavior per p:calendar for this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I will provide a very basic example on how to initialize the time for the first time the date is selected.

*p:calendar*

```
    <p:calendar pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" widgetVar="cal"> 
            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" oncomplete="onDateSelect()"></p:ajax>
    </p:calendar>
```

*JS*

```
var initalDateSelect = true;

function onDateSelect() {

   if(initalDateSelect) {
       myDate = cal.getDate();
       myDate.setHours(7);
       myDate.setMinutes(15);   
       cal.setDate(myDate);
       initalDateSelect = false;
   }

 }
```

Basically the first time the user selects a Date, we get this date and set our hour and minutes and give it back to the calendar.

[image: p:calendar]

Now the next step would be, [pass your initial values from your JSF into the javascript.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709014/how-do-i-pass-jsf-variables-to-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a Hour to a Date (calendar's date) when the p:calendar changes using .

```
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{calendarBean.setToCustomHour}" />

.........

public void setToCustomHour(){

      (Set hour to a Date in JAVA)
}
```